# Publishing failed after upgrade to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: publishing, upgrade, 2013

We have recently upgraded from SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR#2 to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. We are using Oracle 11g R2 as the CMS & Presentation DB. Following the documentation, we also updated the Default Building Blocks using Template Builder. However when we try to publish any DCP or Page we are getting the following error:

```
Unexpected namespace URI: uuid:a13c5753-adfc-4e93-912f-ee3d93b6a828. Expecting: uuid:C695849C-4EFA-4F72-B8F2-68170C9F86C3.
```

where "C695849C-4EFA-4F72-B8F2-68170C9F86C3" is the uuid of the new parameter schema and "a13c5753-adfc-4e93-912f-ee3d93b6a828" is the uuid of the old parameter schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Parameters Schema namespace has changed after upgrade, you will need to manually correct that in each Compound Template that is using a Template Building Block with this Parameters Schema.

You can open the Templates in the Template Builder, but then the previous settings will all be gone, and you need to set them yourself again. Or you can open the Template(s) directly in the CME and go to the Source tab and manually change the namespace mentioned there (to the one which is in your current Parameters Schema).

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed the [Renaming default Parameter Schemas](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A964AE3C-4506-49D4-BA34-A7C95F2A60E6&addHistory=true&query=rename%2520building%2520blocks&scope=&tid=e435ec5c-60a7-49d4-b745-abd99b64d99d&filename=GUID-A964AE3C-4506-49D4-BA34-A7C95F2A60E6.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A964AE3C-4506-49D4-BA34-A7C95F2A60E6&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=rename%2520building%2520blocks&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1400503640883&currentQuery=rename%2520building%2520blocks&currentScope=) step during update.